# Use of specutils' Gaussian1d with parameter estimates

Tags: python, astropy, specutils

I am running the "simple example" from specutils to do some line-fitting.

The demo code is here:

https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting.html

This runs and does what it says.

However I want to use parameter estimation to get an approximation to the initial parameters in the Gaussian, because I am interested in looking at a number of long spectra with a lot of lines in and want to attempt initial fits automatically.

So I modify the specutils.fitting import to

```
from specutils.fitting import fit_lines, estimate_line_parameters
```

and add in

```
e1 = estimate_line_parameters(spectrum, models.Gaussian1D())
a = round(e1.amplitude.value,2)
b = round(e1.fwhm.value,2)
c = round(e1.stddev.value,2)
```

This gives meaningful values and I replace the call to the Gaussian by:

```
g_init = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=a*u.Jy, mean=b*u.um, stddev=c*u.um)
```

then

```
g_fit = fit_lines(spectrum, g_init)
y_fit = g_fit(x*u.um)
```

The initial values I get from the estimator are:

```
initial amplitude= 3.35 initial fwhm = 2.41 initial stddev= 1.02
```

But on looking at the output parameters using g_fit.amplitude.value etc, I get:

```
final amplitude= -0.24 Jy final fwhm = 0.0 um final stddev= 0.0 um
```

for the output values!! If the estimated parameters are correct then the output values should be very close.

What is the issue using the estimators like this - and how do you resolve it?

NOTE: If I replace the parameters in g_init with the values given in the example I then get:

```
initial amplitude= 3.35  initial fwhm =  2.41  initial stddev= 1.02
final amplitude= 3.0471 Jy  final fwhm =  1.9157 um  final stddev= 0.8135 um
```

which agrees with what you would expect from the curve plotted in the example.

FWIW I am running Jupyter Notebook, matplotlib 3.2.2, specutils 1.0, numpy 1.19, python 3.6 all over Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: If you just eyeball a plot of the original data, do the returned parameter estimates look reasonable to you?  It might help to know what your data looks like.

Comment: Hi, Iguananaut. If you go to to the first link you will see the code that I am running  (the standard demo)- it generates the data as essentially a gaussian with a random value added at each point. The code remains the same as that **except** that I add in a call to the estimator from specutils.fitting and include the lines above as described.